# Footer animation works but text not showing

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a simple animated foooter, when i mouse over the div shows, but i cannot get the text to display. It is breaking my head...

```
 //Animated Footer
  $("#foeter")
    .mouseenter(function() {
      $("#invisible").slideDown("1000");
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
      $("#invisible").slideUp("1000");
    });
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rekgd5tc/

Anybody know what i am missing here?

Answer (score 4):

The problem lies in the fact that you are using bootstrap css and the class `.invisible` in bootstrap adds `visibility: hidden`.

Try changing the class name or removing it and using a different selector in your CSS such as the ID.

https://jsfiddle.net/rekgd5tc/1/

```
#invisible {
    display:none;
    background-color: pink;
}

<div id="invisible"> </div>
```

Comment: Totally agree. From now on just unique names for me.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `.invisible` is a predefined bootstrap class that adds `visibility: hidden`, which in your case conflicts with the dynamical `display` settings.

Changing the name of that class to something else solves your problem. In this fiddle I changed it to `.not_visible`: https://jsfiddle.net/u8jkkdh4/

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:-** *this is not an answer for the OP problem, the correct answer is [@stewartside](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2889988/stewartside)'s answer, but just want to show the OP how to achieve same effect with CSS only, no need for javascript*

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/tjknz1zo/)

**CSS:**

```
.foeter {
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  color: #FFFFFF;
  height:20px;
  transition:all 1s;
}
.foeter:hover{
   height:130px;
   transition:all 1s;
}
.inv {
  background-color: pink;
}
.foeter #alwaysThere{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  background-color: #4A527A;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
  <div class="container">
    <footer class="navbar-fixed-bottom foeter">
      <div class="foeter" id="foeter">
        <div class="inv" id="inv">
          <p>
            Wordt dit nu zichtbaar
            <br> Hier komt de info die zichtbaar moet worden
          </p>
          <br> nog meer tekst
          <br> het wordt nu een heel verhaal
          <br>
        </div>
        <!-- invisble -->
        <span id="alwaysThere">
          Altijd visible text.
        </span>
      </div>
      <!-- foeter -->
    </footer>
  </div>
```